# Container failed after restarting docker

Tags: docker

I have 2 containers running redis and postgresql. After restarting docker server, both failed. But it still runs with the status of `Up <> minutes`, but it doesn't seem to run correctly. I run the docker logs on redis and postgresql, these are the logs :

redis:

```
[206] 29 Mar 04:03:27.358 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[10] 29 Mar 04:03:27.433 * Background saving terminated with success
[10] 29 Mar 04:08:28.032 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[10] 29 Mar 04:08:28.038 * Background saving started by pid 207
[207] 29 Mar 04:08:29.412 * DB saved on disk
[207] 29 Mar 04:08:29.413 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[10] 29 Mar 04:08:29.449 * Background saving terminated with success
2014/03/29 04:10:48 no such file or directory
```

postgresql:

```
2014-03-28 11:05:34 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-03-28 10:57:12 UTC
2014-03-28 11:05:34 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2014-03-28 11:05:34 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2014/03/29 04:10:48 no such file or directory
```

They seems to have the same error : `no such file or directory`

Comment: are you mounting volumes with the containers? If so, are the volumes present and available after rebooting? Might help to share some more info on how you're starting the containers and how you're mounting volumes/etc

Answer (score 0):

We've found that restarting docker when containers are running leads to "ghost" containers that docker can't manage.

It's most apparent when upgrading docker - usually we just restart the host when doing so.

Comment: so what happens to those containers. I find that it still fails if I restart the host.